# Appengine without google apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, dns, google-apps

I was using GAE with Gapps on my domain, however it seems that ghs.google.com is unavailable in China.

How can I use GAE on my domain without Gapps?

Edit: A solution I'm considering is using something like a proxy. This way the firewall doesnt see google. By the way, my site is not banned because of its content, it can be acessed normally using appspot. The problem comes from google apps redirections.

Any ideas how I can setup something like this?

Comment: And while we are at, HTTPS access to GAE is also blocked in China (only HTTP to non-domain-named appspot.com currently works). Please vote at the GAE issue tracker at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3334 and http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1570

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting domain to google app engine without google apps.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408229/connecting-domain-to-google-app-engine-without-google-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408229/connecting-domain-to-google-app-engine-without-google-apps) you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Petition your government for redress of grievance? Yes, I know that's not such a hot idea in 中華人民共和國.

Google is quote interested in access to [their services generally](http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/traffic/?r=CN&l=DOCS&csd=1230796800000&ced=1285052400000), but isn't (yet) in a position to tell governments what to do directly.

Answer (score 0):

[AppScale](http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/) is an open-source implementation of the Google App Engine cloud computing interface. It is being developed by researchers in the UC Santa Barbara RACELab.

AppScale enables execution of Google App Engine (GAE) applications on virtualized cluster systems. In particular, AppScale enables users to execute GAE applications using their own clusters with greater scalability and reliability than the GAE SDK provides.

Moreover, AppScale executes automatically and transparently over cloud infrastructures such as the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) and Eucalyptus, the open-source implementation of the AWS interfaces.