# Is it possible to map multiple domains to single Google App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, domain-mapping

I'm developing CMS System that can serve multiple sites at same time, is it possible to map multiple domains to single Google App Engine application?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408229/connecting-domain-to-google-app-engine-without-google-apps/1408472#1408472

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can.

Even better, there is [support for "multitenancy"](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy.html), where you app is automatically partitioned to support multiple domains/namespaces.

What this means is that major APIs support multitenancy (datastore, tasks, memcache), where for each namespace you get a separate "instance" of the API. For example: Domain1 will only see Entities that it created, and domain2 will see it's own.

This means that you don't need to do namespace separation by hand in your code. You do this via a simple servlet Filter by mapping a domain to a namespace.